# What is the best way to use GraphQL with AWS AppSync?

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

Im using AWS AppSync in my react native application. I followed many tutorials , this in particular : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-reactnative.html

In this tutorial, provided by AWS, they use Apollo Graphql : « 
 AWS AppSync integrates with the Apollo GraphQL client for building client applications. AWS provides Apollo plugins for offline support, authorization, and subscription handshaking. You can use the Apollo client directly, or you can use it with some of the client helpers provided in the AWS AppSync SDK. »

But, with the new release of the AWS AppSync documentation, we get another way to work.

So my question is : What is the best way to use GraphQL with AWS AppSync?

Why there is no information about Apollo GraphQL in the documentation while it uses in the tutorial?

Thanks you in advance for your answers/advices.

Comment: Any GraphQL client can call an AWS AppSync endpoint, including Apollo. AWS Amplify as of right now is the recommended client.

Comment: Thank you, ok it is clear for me now.